# Closing Connection object once I got my required ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

Would there be any effect if I close my `Connection` object once I got my `ResultSet`?

```
Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
con.close();
```

Further to this I use my `rs` object and I feel there will not be any impact on it. Because `ResultSet` and `Statement` are in connection with each other.

Comment: From my opinion, if after the `con.close()` there is no other statement than you're okay. But if you want to use the `rs` after the `con.close()` than it will become error.

Comment: Well that would be a NPE btw...

Comment: Closing the connection will invalidates the resultset and statement associated with it. And the better practise is to convert Result set into DTOs instead of directly using resultset.

Comment: Don't do it until you perfectly know what are you doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the resultset soon after you close the connection to the database. Because, when you use `resultset.next()` method, it will send a request to the database in order to fetch the next record; but physically the connection has been closed. So, an `Exception` will be thrown by your statement `resultset.next()`.

Comment: "when you use resultset.next() method, it will send a request to the database in order to fetch the next record" -> doesn't have to be true. This is implementation dependant.

Answer (score 3):

Once the `Connection` is closed other resources (`Statement`s or `ResultSet`s) must not be used.

Comment: When I say `con.close()` how it differs from connection pool and db server?

Answer (score 3):

You mustn't use anything derived from a `Connection` after the connection is closed.

This is actually because things like Result Sets might not be transferred to your machine until you actually use them.  Databases can and do use transfer batching and server cursors - which is a complicated way of saying they only transfer a block of rows to you as you actually request them by moving the result set cursor (for instance with `ResultSet#next()`).

Other parts of the result set, like BLOB or other LOB types, aren't transferred at all until you actually read them out of the result set.  That's because they can be arbitrarily large and the DB driver (okay, a *good* DB driver) wants to minimize the memory it uses in the client.

The DB server itself is usually vastly more sophisticated than the driver (which becomes little more than a communications arbiter), and it's best to leave the 'heavy lifting' (marshalling and temporary storage of result sets) to the DB :-)

So you can see that closing a connection is going to free all the server resources - and there could be many - associated with your query.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot close the connection if you want to access the `ResultSet` after closing. You will lose the `ResultSet` data and will get an exception when you try to access it.

This is because `ResultSet` instances are linked to the DB connection.

Comment: When I say `con.close()` how it differs from connection pool and db server?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I get a connection from Connection pool whilst I get a connection from a DB server. Calling '.close()' in these two different scenarios will completely nullify the connection object?

Comment: Why do you need 2 connections? The one from the `Connection` pool is enough. You should only work with that one. Anyway, it's only the `Connection` from which you got the `ResultSet` that matters.